# Jquery attribute selector difference using Find

Tags: jquery

## 1

```
$('[name='+name+']')
```

VS

## 2

```
$.find('[name='+name+']')
```

#1 results jquery object array. , #2 returns element array

How does jquery determine when to return element vs jquery object..

Comment: Actually, I believe `$.find` is an internal shortcut for Sizzle, and you shouldn't be using it at all. It's not documented, and I'm not sure where you found it, but jQuery doesn't really determine anything, you're just using the wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment below, you're confusing two unrelated functions. (Which is easily done.)

There is a *documented* method of *jQuery instances* called [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which returns a jQuery instance. You call it on instances, not on the `jQuery` function. E.g.:

```
var instance = $("some selector here");
instance.find("some other selector here").doSomething();
```

There is an *internal*, undocumented method on the `jQuery` function called `find`. If you were to use it, you'd do that like this:

```
// Undocumented
var x = $.find("...");
```

That function is completely unrelated to the documented one above, and as it's undocumented, you shouldn't use it.

This is similar to the confusion people have with [`jQuery#each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (a documented API function you call on jQuery instances to iterate their contents) and [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) (a documented API function you call on the `jQuery` function to loop through arbitrary array-like and object structures).

> How does jquery determine when to return element vs jquery object..

Nearly all public API calls return jQuery objects. Internal methods do whatever jQuery needs the internal method to do. :-)

Comment: @faiz: Right, which is not `$.find`. The method you've linked to there is the one I refer to in my opening paragraph as `jQuery#find`, which is a method of jQuery instances. In contrast, `$.find` is a method of the `jQuery` function, an entirely different thing. (It's similar to the difference between [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`jQuery#each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), except that both `each`es are documented.)

Comment: @TJ Both find() return same result. Why would jquery keep 2 different implementation?

Comment: @faiz: Well, not quite the same result, right? Because `$.find` returns an array and `jQuery#find` returns a jQuery instance. I expect `$.find` is an internal function used for various things. In fact, looking at the jQuery source, `$.find` is actually just an alias for `Sizzle` (the selector engine that jQuery uses, which is actually a separate standalone project).

Answer (score -1):

$('[name='+name+']') this will give all element match with "name", but second one  $.find('[name='+name+']') not like this $("parent selector").find('[name='+name+']') this will find inside selected element.